# Фильтр чекбоксами на сайте Django

Tags: python, django

Имеется: 
Сайт с книгами. Модели книг, авторов. View с выводом данных в качестве списка (ListView)

Нужно:
Организовать чекбоксы для фильтрации книг по авторам или по категориям (жанрам). Каждый чекбокс соответствует одному автору или одной категории (жанру)

Код:
models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    """ Модель, представляющая книги """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    # ForeignKey использую, потому что книга может иметь только одного автора, но автор много книг
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text='Введите краткое описание книги')
    isbn = models.CharField('ISBN', max_length=13, help_text='13 символова <a href="https://www.isbn-international.org/content/what-isbn">ISBN номера</a> книги')
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, help_text='Выберите жанр книги')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """ Возвращает URL для доступа к странице книги"""
        return reverse('book-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def display_genre(self):
        return ', '.join([genre.name for genre in self.genre.all()[:3]])


class Author(models.Model):
    """ Модель представляет автора """
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_death = models.DateField('Died', null=True, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """ Возвращает url для доступа к странице автора"""
        return reverse('author-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}, {}'.format(self.last_name, self.first_name)


class Genre(models.Model):
    """ Модель, представляющая жанры книг"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Введите жанр книги")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
class BookListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Book
    paginate_by = 15
```

Comment: Сделай форму. При сабмите отдавай данные на бек и фильтруй.

Comment: Если есть знания JavaScript - лучше это организовать на нём, а результат передавать на сервер и интерпретировать во views.py. Например, есть вот такой мультиселект https://www.positronx.io/multiselect-dropdown-list-with-checkboxes-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фильтр по жанру например можно сделать так. Во `views.py` в класс добавьте :

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class BookListView(ListView):
    model = Book
    paginate_by = 15

class Genre:
"""Жанры"""
    def get_genres(self):
        return Genre.objects.all()


class FilterBooksView(Genre, ListView):
    paginate_by = 5
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Book.objects.filter(genre__in=self.request.GET.getlist("genre")).distinct()                          
        return queryset
```

ну и в шаблоне страницы

```
<form action="{% url 'filter' %}" method="get" name="filter">
  <h1 >Жанры</h3>
        {% for genre in view.get_genres %}
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checked" name="genre" value="{{ genre.id }}">
                    <span>{{ genre.name }}</span>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Найти</button>
</form>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ......
    path("filter/", views.FilterBooksView.as_view(), name='filter'),
    ......
]
```

если что не понятно, спрашивайте.
Если надо будет добавить еще n-ое количество фильтров
добавляете представления в класс `Gener` (Можете переименовать для лучшего чтения кода, например если добавить еще и авторов `GenerAuthor` ).

```
def get_author(self):
    return Author.objects.all()
```

И в классе поиска изменить `queryset` на:

```
queryset = Book.objects.filter(
    Q(genre__in=self.request.GET.getlist("genre")) |
    Q(first_name__in=self.request.GET.getlist("first_name"))
).distinct()
```

и добавить `from django.db.models import Q`

Ну и добавить поля в форму в шаблоне. Единственное что вы наверное зря разбили имя и фамилию автора, я бы объединил для однозначного поиска по автору. Если есть знания ajax то лучше сделать с его использованием .